# Nginx cannot reach to backend

Tags: nginx

nginx cannot reach to backend , follow photo is nginx logs

nginx logs

[image: 1]

here is the docker-compose

docker-compose

[image: 2]

I am trying to setup laravel project using docker . Docker containers are running , such as database,web service,backend service.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual data, post it as code-formatted text.

Comment: make sure that you have default.conf file in `./docker-compose/nginx` directory or it would be empty in the container when you start it